# Non inverting DC-DC converter that makes fix 4V from a decreasing voltage from 4,2V to 2,8V?

Tags: voltage, batteries, dc-dc-converter, switching-regulator

Is it possible to make a a non inverting DC-DC converter that makes a fix 4V from a Li-ion battery's voltage. I need about 1,5A.
The input voltage starts from 4,2V and decreasing to 2,8V as the battery discharging. 
Could you recommend an IC or a chematic that has only SMD parts?

Thank you!

Comment: Think about a zeta or a sepic these will go under over .

Comment: It should be possible. Did you search for buck-boost converters?

Comment: Is it possible:? yes. Check: https://webench.ti.com/power-designer/switching-regulator. VtC because the question is too broad (many solutions possible) and therefore not really answerable.

Comment: `Could you recommend an IC or a [s]chematic that has only SMD parts?` No because that's your job as an engineer.

Comment: I am a student... Thanks.

Comment: @Tardief to put this more formally, we have rules that govern which questions are on- and off-topic here. Asking for IC recommendations is explicitly off-topic as it is a product recommendation request; and so is asking for a complete schematics, as that is lacking focus and own effort narrowing things down.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The close reason is insane. Related arguments less sane than is useful, alas.

Comment: Here are many [buck boost converter ICs](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-voltage-regulators-dc-dc-switching-regulators/739?k=buck+boost&k=&pkeyword=buck+boost&sv=0&pv1098=322171&pv1098=322172&pv1098=323620&pv1098=323621&pv1098=323622&pv1098=323626&pv1098=323627&pv1098=323628&pv1098=323629&pv1098=323630&pv1098=323632&pv1098=323634&pv1098=323637&pv1098=323639&pv1098=323640&pv1098=323641&pv1098=323642&pv1098=323652&sf=0&FV=-8%7C739&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25). Some will be suitable for your Vin and power range.

Comment: [closer match](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/pmic-voltage-regulators-dc-dc-switching-regulators/739?FV=1098%7C322171%2C1098%7C322172%2C1098%7C323620%2C1098%7C323621%2C1098%7C323622%2C1098%7C323626%2C1098%7C323627%2C1098%7C323628%2C1098%7C323629%2C1098%7C323630%2C1098%7C323632%2C1098%7C323634%2C1098%7C323637%2C1098%7C323639%2C1098%7C323640%2C1098%7C323641%2C1098%7C323642%2C1098%7C323652%2C1471%7C61153%2C-8%7C739%2C1429%7C231255%2C1429%7C231500%2C1429%7C233086%2C1429%7C249171&quantity=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&k=buck+boost&pageSize=25&pkeyword=buck+boost)

Comment: Same ol’ SE. Same old arguments. The OP is asking a reasonable question, and y’all get wrapped around the axle if they deign to ask about a specific solution. The horror!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's several ways to do this.

- Use a buck-boost converter

This kind of device adapts based on the ratio between input and output voltage. They have three modes: Buck, LDO and Boost. Since your max LiPo voltage is 4.2V or so, the converter would be in LDO mode, then Boost mode as the battery drains.

- Use a boost followed by LDO

Before there were buck-boost solutions out there, this is the way it was done. If you could boost up to say 4.5V then regulate to 4V, the losses at 1.5A would be 750mW max. Not ideal.

- Use boost, followed by buck

Boost up to 5V, then regulate to 4V using a second buck DCDC. Conveniently, there are lots of solutions for the first part that are specific to USB.

Happy hunting...